# logging in java web start without jdk?

Tags: java, java-web-start

I have a JWS application that runs fine on my Windows 10 laptop.  Now I need to have it working on a colleague's Windows 10 laptop.  He is not a developer so does not have the JDK.

For me to figure out what was going wrong on my box, I had gone into the Java Console and enabled tracing and logging.  Then in a command shell I

```
set JAVAWS_TRACE_NATIVE=1
set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
javaws app.jnlp
```

But since he does not have the JDK, he does not have the Java Console, nor can he test the .jnlp file using javaws app.jnlp

How can I figure out what is going wrong on his machine?  It will not even run the jar file.  How can I find out why?

Comment: If you're going to need this further out than the immediate future, especially past JDK 9, you should start looking now for another solution. The entire Applet and WebStart environment is deprecated in JDK 9 and JDK 10, and AFAIK has been removed from JDK 11, due to be released at then end of this month (September, 2018).

Comment: Great.  Finally got this to work after tons of time invested.  Now they're going to deprecate it?  What a waste of time and effort.  How dare they?  So what is everyone using for a replacement?

Answer (score 1):

The only solution is to install JDK or jvm on his laptop. No other walk-rounds.

Comment: My understanding is that anybody with the JRE installed should be able to run JWS apps.  He has the JRE but nothing happens when he tries to launch this standard test app: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/examples/dist/webstart_ComponentArch_DynamicTreeDemo/JavaWebStartAppPage_No_Codebase.html

Comment: Check if JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME is set up correctly.